# What is the legal requirements of earning money on the internet

Tags: tax-law

I am planning to provide an internet service that accepts payments through

1. Bit coin
2. PayPal
3. Visa

For now, I have not legally registered this as a company or planning to pay tax for the income.
Is it illegal to do this? And what do I need to do before starting to earn income?

Comment: "Registering as a company" is generally not an issue, except in some municipalities who have aggressive views of what constitutes a business thus requiring a business license. You can do things for money, as long as you pay the relevant state and federal taxes (income and sales, depending on state).

Answer (score 2):

It is illegal to not declare income to the IRS.

Self-employment tax rules apply to all income. Bitcoin is treated as property and is taxable.

https://www.irs.gov/uac/newsroom/irs-virtual-currency-guidance